# Не отображаются новости в Redmine. Куда копать?

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, redmine

Список новостей отображается, но когда раскрываю новость выдает ошибку 500 с дефолтным текстом из 500.html. В логах вот:

```
Started GET "/redmine/news/1" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-06-08 12:40:05 +0300
Processing by NewsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Current user: eri (id=1)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `reverse!' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>):
  app/controllers/news_controller.rb:62:in `show'
```

Установка на дебиан из пакета. Как посмотреть поподробней в чем проблема?

UPD Проблема возникает только под моим пользователем, который был самый первый админ.

Comment: вероятно, подробнее можно посмотреть в `app/controllers/news_controller.rb` в районе 62-й строки.

Comment: не думаю что проблема в коде. скорее в данных. как посмотреть стек вызовов поглубже?

Comment: вероятно, где-то в недрах redmine-а надо присвоить переменной `config.log_level` значение `:debug` (или что-то в этом духе).

Comment: удалил пользователя, создание с тем же логином не помогло, с другим логином все впорядке